# Erro ao copiar banco de dados no SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

estou tentando realizar a cópia de um banco de dados para o mesmo servidor mas estou me deparando com o erro abaixo:

> Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.
>
> The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1)
>   reached the maximum allowed (1);  resulting in failure. This occurs
>   when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
>   MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Tentei achar essa propriedade "MaximumErrorCount" para tentar alterar, mas não consegui encontrar. Também não sei se esse é o caminho para resolver o problema.

Estou usando o sql server 2008

Comment: A mensagem diz que ocorreu um erro ao copiar... Mesmo que você aumentasse a tolerância da quantidade de erros, continuaria não copiando com sucesso. Acho que a melhor forma de resolver o problema é encontrar a mensagem exata do erro em algum log.

Comment: Voce tem razão @Renan .. voltei e analise outras linhas de código e encontrei um erro na tabela documentos: 
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.DOCUMENTOS' and the index name 'IndexUnicDocumentos_DocumentosNumero'

Comment: Chave duplicada. Você tem duas opções: 1) desligar a validação do índice, copiar, depois ligar a validação de novo ou 2) exorcizar a chave duplicada. Em geral as pessoas que fazem a segunda opção são mais felizes.

Comment: Funcionou Renan, Valeu pelo help